# Why can't BFS convert an undirected graph to a DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

Say I have a connected and *undirected* graph G, and I want to convert G to a DAG. The solution is clear to me: I will assign each node a number, and then, each edge (u,v) will be directed u->v only if the number that is assigned to u is smaller than v.

However, this was not my initial solution. At first, I thought, why not just running BFS? I know that BFS would never generate a cycle, only a tree or a cross edge (which *do not* create cycles). I know that BFS is problematic with directed graphs, but the given graph G is *undirected*. I was told that BFS won't work here, but wasn't told why. I tried to think why by myself but I still don't get it.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I was told..."*: I don't see any problem with BFS. Do you have any reference for the claim? If the graph is not connected, you might need to restart a BFS at some unvisited node, until you have covered the whole graph.

Comment: @trincot Me neither! Basically it is a question from an exam which states problematic solutions, one of them is "using BFS" (sadly it is not explained why). The graph *is* connected (as I've stated).

Comment: Try to come up with a node numbering scheme (based on the order BFS goes) that satisfies the requirements you laid out at the beginning, thus proving that it works.

Comment: If you imagine that the BFS algorithm assigns an ever increasing number to each unvisited node it finds, and when it finds a visited node, it sets the edge direction from that node towards the current, then you actually just do what your initial solution did, except that it steers a bit more which nodes are numbered next.

Answer (score 1):

BFS works fine.  If you process all of each vertex's edges in the order in which you discover those vertices, then every edge will go from an older vertex to a newer one.

The result is consistent with your numbering scheme if you number the vertices in BFS order.

There are ways to attempt it with BFS that *don't* work... but there are ways to attempt *anything* that don't work.

Comment: Specifically, BFS with a data structure to keep track of what has been processed will work.  BFS without that data structure will result in infinite traversal of loops (until you run out of memory).  But you need that data structure anyways to record the answer!